# React-Native FBSDK Share Dialog only works in simulator (iOS)

Tags: dialog, react-native, share, facebook-sdk-4.0, fbsdk

I'm trying to share a link through the React-Native-FBSDK library using the `ShareDialog`. I've got my code set up like so:

```
const shareContent = {
  contentType: 'link',
  contentDescription: 'Stuff here',
  contentTitle: 'Share Title',
  contentUrl: 'https://google.com',
  imageUrl: someUrl
}

ShareDialog.canShow(shareContent).then((canShow) => {
  canShow && ShareDialog.show(shareContent);
}
```

This code works in the simulator when it opens in a Safari WebView but when I load it on a device with the Facebook app installed, it opens a model over my app but it only uses the url I give it, then it fills in all the other data from the meta tags on the page instead of using my code. Is there something I need to do to get this to work with the native app?

[image]
[image]
.

iOS 10, react-native 0.30.0, react-native-fbsdk 0.4.0

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue. My solution is to use the ShareButton instead of ShareDialog. It works perfectly in my iPhone 10.2.

```
import {ShareButton} from "react-native-fbsdk";


const shareModel = {
        contentType: 'link',
        contentUrl: this.url,
        contentTitle: this.title,
        contentDescription: this.description,
        imageUrl: this.thumb
    };

<ShareButton shareContent={shareModel}/>
```

Comment: what would the value of this.thumb? does it allow external URL?